# Java: Crear métodos con valores por defecto

Tags: java, polimorfismo, parámetros

Existen lenguajes como javascript los cuales aceptan que sus funciones tengan un valor por defecto. Por ejemplo:

```javascript
function times(number = 3, mult = 2) {
    return number * mult;
}

times();                // --> 6
times(5);               // --> 10
times(undefined, 4);    // --> 12
times(5, 3);            // --> 15
```

¿Es posible lograr este comportamiento en Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque en Java no existe el concepto como tal el concepto de parámetros por defecto se puede implementar la **sobre carga de métodos**, el cual nos permite tener el mismo método con distintos parámetros.

Lo que se tendría que hacer es considerar cada caso:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(times());
        System.out.println(times(5));
        System.out.println(times(null, 4));
        System.out.println(times(5, 3));

    }

    // No params
    private static double times() {
        return times(3, 2);
    }
    // Just the first param
    private static double times(double a) {
        return times(a, 2);
    }
    // Just the second param
    private static double times(Double a, double b) {
        return times(3, b);
    }
    // The two params
    private static double times(double a, double b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Como se puede observar `times(Double a, double b)` es usado para cuando no existe el primer argumento, sin embargo esto es porque se está trabajando con un tipo de dato primitivo, De manera ideal la implementación debería ser parecida a esta:

```java
private static void customMethod() {
    customMethod(default_1, default_2);
}

private static void customMethod(CustomObject a) {
    customMethod(a, default_2);
}

private static void customMethod(CustomObject a, CustomObject b) {
    // Just the second param
    if (null == a) {
        a = default_1;
    } 

    /* Tu código con ambos parámetros va aquí*/
    
}
```

Otra forma de lograr el mismo comportamiento es con un **Fluent Interface**, el cual funciona funciona de forma parecida a una secuencia de setters, solamente que estos retornan el mismo objeto al que pertenecen.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Times().times());
        System.out.println(new Times().setFirstNumber(5).times());
        System.out.println(new Times().setSecondNumber(4).times());
        System.out.println(new Times().setFirstNumber(5).setSecondNumber(3).times());

    }

    private static class Times {
        private double first_number = 3;
        private double second_number = 2;

        public Times setFirstNumber(double number) {
            this.first_number = number;
            return this;
        }

        public Times setSecondNumber(double number) {
            second_number = number;
            return this;
        }

        public double times() {
            return this.first_number * this.second_number;
        }
    }

}
```

Personalmente creo que el diseño FluentInterface es mucho más escalable y útil para este tipo de casos.

Comment: Hay dos errores de concepto en esta respuesta: 1) El término "polimorfismo paramétrico" NO EXISTE en java, a lo que te refieres con este término se llama sobrecarga de métodos, y 2) Lo que muestras como patrón Builder no lo es. El patrón Builder es un patrón creacional y el ejemplo que pones no construye ningún objeto, simplemente usa un API fluida (fluent API) sobre objetos de la clase `Times`.

Comment: Por últimpo, el método `private static double times(Double, double)` declarado en el primer bloque de código no hace uso de primer parámetro. Esto es un smell code denominado [Código Muerto (*Dead Code*)](https://refactoring.guru/smells/dead-code).

Comment: @E.Betanzos también yo llamaba eso sobrecarga, sin embargo, parece ser que la sobrecarga en realidad es en clases totalmente independientes, según [este blog](https://ifgeekthen.everis.com/es/polimorfismo-en-java-programaci%C3%B3n-orientada-objetos) y la [Universidad Politécnica de Valencia](https://riunet.upv.es/handle/10251/104296?show=full) el polimorfismo paramétrico permite que una función acepte como argumentos un número potencialmente infinito de tipos diferentes (de datos)

Comment: Es como una subclasificación del polimorfismo. Se puede dividir en **sobre carga, paramétrico y subtipado (o de inclusión)**

Comment: Gracias, ya está actualizado el concepto de **Builder Pattern** a **Fluent Interface**

Comment: Si te fijas bien el video de la universidad contradice completamente lo dice el blog. El [polimorfismo paramétrico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) se refiere a que la implementación de una función sea capaz de funcionar correctamente independientemente del tipo de parámetro que reciba. Esto se logra en Java usando genéricos y no con sobrecarga de métodos. La sobrecarga de métodos es un tipo de [polimorfismo ad hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism) no paramétrico.

Comment: Leyendo de nuevo mi primer comentario creo que no es correcto decir que en Java no existe el polimorfismo paramétrico. Lo que intentaba decir es que el ejemplo que pones no es esto sino sobrecarga (un tipo de polimorfismo ad hoc).