# Aplicar varios filtros a consulta de MYSQL con JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Les voy a comentar mi problema. Tengo una base de datos en mysql y hago las consultas desde Java usando JDBC. Estoy tratando de hacer un filtrado de datos, ya que quiero poder filtrar datos no solamente por el nombre, si no también por otros datos. Tal como ven, mi código tiene muchas sentencias SQL, trate de juntarlas junto a un array, pero solamente funciona la primera sentencia, si hago otras, saltan excepciones, solamente funciona si hago solamente 1 consulta individual. Mi problema es ese y me gustaría encontrarle una solución. Tengo mucho código silenciado, ya que mi idea es tener una sentencia que lo englobe todo.

```java
public static Comics[] filtadroBBDD(String nombreC, String numeroC, String varianteC, String firmaC,
            String nomEditorialC, String formatoC, String procedenciaC, String fechaC, String guionistaC,
            String nomDibujanteC) {

        reiniciarBBDD();

        String nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom, formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom,
                guionistaCom, dibujanteCom;
        Comics comics[] = null;

        String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomComic = '" + nombreC + "';";
        String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where numComic = '" + numeroC + "';";
        String sql3 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomVariante = '" + varianteC + "';";
        String sql4 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where firma = '" + firmaC + "';";
        String sql5 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomEditorial = '" + nomEditorialC + "';";
        String sql6 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where formato = '" + formatoC + "';";
        String sql7 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where procedencia = '" + procedenciaC + "';";
        String sql8 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where anioPubli = '" + fechaC + "';";
        String sql9 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomGuionistas = '" + guionistaC + "';";
        String sql10 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where nomDibujantes = '" + nomDibujanteC + "';";
//      String []sentenciasSQL = {sql1,sql2,sql3,sql4,sql5,sql6,sql7,sql8,sql9,sql10};
        String[] sentenciasSQL = { sql1 };

//      String sql = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd WHERE nomComic = '" + nombreC + "' AND numComic = '" + numeroC
//              + "' AND nomVariante = '" + varianteC + "' AND firma = '" + firmaC + "' AND nomEditorial = '"
//              + nomEditorialC + "' and formato = '" + formatoC + "' AND procedencia = '" + procedenciaC
//              + "' AND anioPubli = '" + fechaC + "' AND nomGuionista = '" + guionistaC + "' AND nomDibujante = '"
//              + nomDibujanteC + "';";

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < sentenciasSQL.length; i++) {
                ResultSet rs = DBManager.getComic(sentenciasSQL[i]);

                do {
                    nombreCom = rs.getString("nomComic");
                    numeroCom = rs.getString("numComic");
                    varianteCom = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                    firmaCom = rs.getString("firma");
                    editorialCom = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                    formatoCom = rs.getString("formato");
                    procedenciaCom = rs.getString("procedencia");
                    fechaCom = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                    guionistaCom = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                    dibujanteCom = rs.getString("nomDibujante");

                    FiltrolistComics.add(new Comics(nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom,
                            formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom, guionistaCom, dibujanteCom));

                } while (rs.next());
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        comics = new Comics[FiltrolistComics.size()];
        comics = FiltrolistComics.toArray(comics);
        return comics;
    }

    public static void reiniciarBBDD() {
        FiltrolistComics.clear();
        listComics.clear();
    }
```

EDIT

He modificado tu codigo para que me funcionase, y sigo teniendo duda. El orden en que se toman los datos no es consecutivo. Eso hace que si meto un dato por ejemplo en "editorial" y esta en la 3º posicion, pues se toma en la posicion 5. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public static Comics[] filtadroBBDD(String nombreC, String numeroC, String varianteC, String firmaC,
            String editorialC, String formatoC, String procedenciaC, String fechaC, String guionistaC,
            String dibujanteC) throws SQLException {

        reiniciarBBDD();

        String nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom, formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom,
        guionistaCom, dibujanteCom;
        Comics comics[] = null;

        ArrayList<String> strFilter = new ArrayList<>();

        String connector = " WHERE ";
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd");
        if (nombreC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("nomComic = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(nombreC);
        }
        if (numeroC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("numComic = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(numeroC);
        }
        if (varianteC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("nomVariante = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(varianteC);
        }
        if (firmaC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("firma = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(firmaC);
        }
        if (editorialC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("nomEditorial = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(editorialC);
        }
        if (formatoC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("formato = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(formatoC);
        }
        if (procedenciaC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("procedencia = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(procedenciaC);
        }
        if (fechaC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("anioPubli = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(fechaC);
        }
        if (guionistaC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("nomGuionista = ?");
            connector = " AND ";
            strFilter.add(guionistaC);
        }
        if (dibujanteC.length() != 0) {
            sql.append(connector).append("nomDibujante = ?");
            strFilter.add(dibujanteC);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombreC);
        System.out.println("Numero: " + numeroC);
        System.out.println("Variante: " + varianteC);
        System.out.println("Firma: " + firmaC);
        System.out.println("Editorial: " + editorialC);
        System.out.println("Formato: " + formatoC);
        System.out.println("Procedencia: " + procedenciaC);
        System.out.println("Fecha: " + fechaC);
        System.out.println("Guionista: " + guionistaC);
        System.out.println("Dibujante: " + dibujanteC + "\n");

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < strFilter.size();) {
                ps.setString(++i, strFilter.get(i-1));
            }
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            
            while(rs.next()){
                nombreCom = rs.getString("nomComic");
                numeroCom = rs.getString("numComic");
                varianteCom = rs.getString("nomVariante");
                firmaCom = rs.getString("firma");
                editorialCom = rs.getString("nomEditorial");
                formatoCom = rs.getString("formato");
                procedenciaCom = rs.getString("procedencia");
                fechaCom = rs.getString("anioPubli");
                guionistaCom = rs.getString("nomGuionista");
                dibujanteCom = rs.getString("nomDibujante");
                FiltrolistComics.add(new Comics(nombreCom, numeroCom, varianteCom, firmaCom, editorialCom,
                        formatoCom, procedenciaCom, fechaCom, guionistaCom, dibujanteCom));
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        comics = new Comics[FiltrolistComics.size()];
        comics = FiltrolistComics.toArray(comics);
        return comics;
    }
```

Comment: `String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd where "+nombreColumna+" = '" + ValorCampo + "';";`

Comment: Eso no me sirve, lo que quiero es no solamente mostrar todo con 1 campo, si no con el campo que quiera

Comment: por eso es que hay que poner una variable nombreColumna

Comment: @MisterioRojo, en este caso el método te pide **TODOS** los parámetros, por lo cual debes de enviarle todos aunque no los vayas a aplicar. Puedes cambiar el código para hacerlo con un HashMap o un GSON para evitar enviar datos de más, otra cosa que puedes hacer es la sobrecarga de métodos (no conviene en realidad, pues terminarías haciendo lo mismo pero varias veces) o adoptar un diseño tipo fluent interface

Comment: Checa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455230/java-crear-m%c3%a9todos-con-valores-por-defecto) que tengo, puedes crear una clase anidada que te ayude a crear tus filtros, incluso la puedes personalizar para cambiar el conector, por ejemplo para que en vez de usar AND, use OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Anotaciones

- Tu código es **súper vulnerable** a inyecciones de datos, te indicaría que hagas uso de [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), aparte de que brinda mayor seguridad es más rápido en ejecución (según recuerdo de los resultados de pruebas en nanosegundos de un vídeo que vi hace años)
- Ya que todos tus campos son tipo `String` se simplifica el asunto. y sólo hacemos uso de [PreparedStatement#setString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,java.lang.String)), de lo contrario una solución podría ser el uso de if's y del operador instanceof
- Si tienes duda del uso de PreparedStatement, te recomiendo leer el [tutorial oficial de Oracle de JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- La comparación de los filtros se hace por capas, se indica que un filtro no se debe aplicar si el campo es null, es decir, si `name == null` entonces ese filtro no se aplica
- Cambié el español por inglés, así que obviamente no va a funcionar con tu código, será cosa de que adaptes el nombre de las columnas y variables

```java
public void createComicFilter(String name, String number, String variant,
              String sign, String editorial, String format,
              String procedence, String year, String writer,
              String sketcher) throws SQLException {

    ArrayList<String> strFilter = new ArrayList<>();

    String connector = " WHERE ";
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT * FROM comicsbbdd");
    if (name != null) {
        sql.append(connector).append("name = ?");
        connector = " AND ";
        strFilter.add(name);
    }
    if (number != null) {
        sql.append(connector).append("number = ?");
        connector = " AND ";
        strFilter.add(number);
    }
    if (variant != null) {
        sql.append(connector).append("variant = ?");
        connector = " AND ";
        strFilter.add(variant);
    }

    // Así por cada campo

    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < strFilter.size(); ) {
        ps.setString(++i, strFilter.get(i - 1));
    }
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
//  Aquí ya haces el manejo de tus datos
    while(rs.next()){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dejo la modificacion en el post, sigo teniendo errores, pero menos. Muchas gracias.